# No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.datetime"

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, gsettings

I am trying to add the year to my clock on my panel.
From here

https://superuser.com/questions/443982/how-can-i-show-the-current-year-in-ubuntus-clock-indicator-applet

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'"
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.datetime”
```

7/29/18

After some new installations, these run without error.
However I still have no year.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'"
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "'%a, %d. %h  %H:%M %Y'"
```

@DK Bose @AlexP 
I thought this would work to show century. Can anyone see if there is a mistake I made ?
[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? For the current version, 18.04, try https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1173/datetime-format/

Comment: I installed but can not figure out how to run it. @AlexP

Comment: FYI the `com.canonical.indicator.datetime` scheme is located in [`indicator-datetime`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=com.canonical.indicator.datetime&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any). Try to install it.

Comment: @KD Bose Using Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Mate desktop. Can I have a signature to avoid having to put this info in every time I post?

Comment: No, there are no "signatures" and it may not be correct the next time you post. You can add the tags when you create the question though. Or you can [edit] and add them after.

Comment: I may be able to solve the problem using dconf. I looked for a tutorial but found none. It looks like dconf is complex.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.
I had to set format to custom.

I used `dconf-editor` and went to `org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/`. I set format to "*custom*" and custom format to `%a %b %d %Y %I:%M %p`.

NOTE: If you accidentally delete your panel, you get to do this all over again.

Comment: @guntbert Done.